# How to convert string date into valid date format in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have string date in `yymmdd` format, for example `150202`

I want to convert this string into a valid date in format `yyyymmdd`, e.g. `20150202`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how will you decide it's 2015 or 1915?

Comment: Have you made some research before asking? Tested some code? This is a really common question and you have lot of samples here in SO.

Comment: SQL Server `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` don't have any format associated with them - they're stored in binary bytes

Comment: Stroing date's as string is a bad practice .. you can read more here:https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: I agree with @Deepshikha. If you known that 150202 means 20150202 just concat "20" and "150202" and than convert this string into date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert your string to datetime and then do that you want with it

```
declare @dt varchar(6) = '150213'
select CONVERT(datetime, @dt, 112)
```

---

Do another `CONVERT` to transform it to `yyyymmdd` format.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @dt, 112), 112)
```

Comment: Did you test it? `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: @wewesthemenace: works just fine for me (SQL Server 2014 - US English language)

Comment: @wewesthemenace, i improved my answer, i used 'yyddmm' format for string. it is 'yymmdd' now

Comment: @marc_s, it's `151302` before the edit. @Ash, thanks!

Comment: @mohan111, it is coming as varchar and output is datetime, which can be displayed in many formats

Comment: @Ash, I edited the answer if you don't mind. You can delete it if you want.

Comment: my quick question guys select REPLACE(CONVERT(datetime, '150202', 112),'-','') i tried like this it has changed to other format instead of replacing '-'

Answer (score 0):

may this will work

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '150202', 112)
```

for all date conversions

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

instead of select CONVERT(datetime, '150202', 112)
its better to use "select TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '150202', 112)" 
while using try_convert if there is any error it will returns null,if we are using convert it will returns error when conversion fails.